# Install pip module from a rails app on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I have an rails app deployed on heroku. This app depends on one python module, https://github.com/clips/pattern. Based on documentation of `pattern`, I could install by two ways:

1: `cd pattern-2.5; python setup.py install`

> creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pattern error: could
>   not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pattern': Read-only
>   file system

2: `pip install pattern`

> bash: pip: command not found

Please, advise me how to install pattern. I found a similar question, [How to install python module on Heroku cedar stack with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591433/how-to-install-python-module-on-heroku-cedar-stack-with-rails), but it just doesn't work for me.

Comment: for your first method, try to use `sudo python setup.py install`. For your second method, try to install pip. see this link http://filon.us/slava/?p=189    . Then use :sudo pip install pattern

Comment: I couldn't use `sudo` command on heroku.

Comment: this post may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591433/how-to-install-python-module-on-heroku-cedar-stack-with-rails

Comment: Thanks :). I saw this one as well. I follow and i got `Readonly file system`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Buildpacks are the mechanism Heroku uses to build your application including installing dependencies. Pip is not installed by default, the Python buildpack itself pulls this dependency in. You could use the multi-buildpack which allows you to include several buildpacks.

Multi buildpack - https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi

Python buildpack - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python

Ruby buildpack - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby